# multiple tickers backtesting

Tags: r, quantmod, trading, back-testing

I have built the following model which backtests only spy. 
My issue is that I want to apply this trading strategy to multiple tickers (e.g. both qqq and spy).

How do I do this?
See below:

```
getSymbols("spy",from ="2000-01-01", to="2015-01-01")
SPY<-adjustOHLC(SPY)
rsi <- RSI(Cl(SPY),2)
smashort<-SMA(Cl(SPY),10)
smalong<-SMA(Cl(SPY),200)
adx<-ADX(HLC(SPY),10)
adx<-adx[,4]
close<-Cl(SPY)

signal<-ifelse(rsi<15 & close<smashort & smalong<close &adx>27,1,0)
for(i in 1:nrow(signal))
{signal<-ifelse(lag(signal)==1 & close<smashort,1,ifelse(rsi<15 & close<smashort & smalong<close & adx>27,1,0))}
signal<-lag(signal,1)
signal[is.na(signal)] <- 0
ret <- ROC(Cl(SPY))
ret[1] <- 0
equity<-exp(cumsum(ret*signal))
plot(equity)
```

Please see below for the multiple tickers version:

> 

```html
stockData <- new.env() #Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
symbols = c("TLT", "USO")
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo',from = "2016-9-01",to = Sys.Date())
for(symbol in symbols){
  assign(symbol,adjustOHLC(get(symbol, pos=.GlobalEnv), symbol.name=symbol, 
                           adjust=c("split"), use.Adjusted=FALSE))
}

x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  x[[i]] <- get(symbols[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment 
  x[[i]]$sma <-SMA(Cl(x[[i]]),10)
  x[[i]]$rsi <-RSI(Cl(x[[i]]),2)
  x[[i]]$close <-(Cl(x[[i]]))
  x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0)
 
for(i in length(x[[i]]$signal))
{x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(lag(x[[i]]$signal)==1 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0))}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be easily done using `quantstrat`. See the demo folder in the package (See the RSI strategy in the demo folder), or google multiple tutorials online about it.

```
devtools::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```

In your code snippet, this section doesn't make sense as you are trying to loop over a vector operation:

```
for(i in length(x[[i]]$signal))
{x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(lag(x[[i]]$signal)==1 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0))}
```

Also `for(i in length(x[[i]]$signal))` simply returns i = length of vector.  Maybe you wanted something like `for(i in 1:NROW(x[[i]]$signal))`.

It looks like you want something like this:

```
x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
    x[[i]] <- get(symbols[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment 
    x[[i]]$sma <-SMA(Cl(x[[i]]),10)
    x[[i]]$rsi <-RSI(Cl(x[[i]]),2)
    x[[i]]$close <-(Cl(x[[i]]))
    x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0)
    x[[i]]$signal2 <-ifelse(lag.xts(x[[i]]$signal) ==1 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0))
}
```

Comment: i will try to use quanstrat but i m also trying to get it right without it. this is what i used and i think it solves the provlem. however i have a problem with the second for loop. can you please help me with that? i dont understand what goes wrong as the for loop works with single ticker as you can see above . see the code below

Comment: x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  x[[i]] <- get(symbols[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment 
  x[[i]]$sma <-SMA(Cl(x[[i]]),10)
  x[[i]]$rsi <-RSI(Cl(x[[i]]),2)
  x[[i]]$close <-(Cl(x[[i]]))
  x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0)
 
for(i in nrow(x[[i]]$signal))
{x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(lag(x[[i]]$signal)==1 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<15 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0))}

Comment: @np2000 have updated answer that appears to correct your error in your code snippet.  Try using `traceback()` and insert `browser()` in parts of your code that are causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

thank you FX Quant Trader. i have figured out another solution. see attache`

```html
x <- list() 
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  x[[i]] <- get(symbols[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment 
  x[[i]]$sma <-SMA(Cl(x[[i]]),10)
  x[[i]]$rsi <-RSI(Cl(x[[i]]),2)
  x[[i]]$close <-(Cl(x[[i]]))
  x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<10 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0)
  for(k in 1:nrow(x[[i]]$signal))
{x[[i]]$signal<-ifelse(lag(x[[i]]$signal)==1 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,ifelse(x[[i]]$rsi<10 & x[[i]]$close<x[[i]]$sma,1,0))}

x[[i]]$signal<-lag(x[[i]]$signal,1)
x[[i]]$signal[is.na(x[[i]]$signal)] <- 0

x[[i]]$ret <- ROC(Cl(x[[i]]$close))
x[[i]]$ret[1] <- 0

x[[i]]$equity<-exp(cumsum(ret*x[[i]]$signal))
plot(x[[i]]$equity)
}
```

`